# How to manually setID for new row? Disable autoincrement. Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have that entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "schema_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "schema_name")
private String schemaName;

@Nationalized
@Lob
@Column(name = "schema_ERD")
private String schemaERD;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_idFK")
private Users users;

... getters setters
```

I am adding new rows like that:

```
Schemas schemas = new Schemas();
schemas.setSchemaERD(...);
schemas.setSchemaName(...);
schemas.setUsers(...;
schemasRepository.save(schemas);
```

Everything works but my ID is autoincremented. I have reason to disable that.

**Is this possible to do something like that? --->**

```
Schemas schemas = new Schemas();
schemas.setId(100);
schemas.setSchemaERD(...);
schemas.setSchemaName(...);
schemas.setUsers(...;
schemasRepository.save(schemas);
```

I am all time getting erros: about nulls or something else. In some ways i am not getting error but my row will be added with autoincremented id...

Can someone help? :(

Comment: Remove the very thing which is generating the value: `@GeneratedValue`

Comment: omg i am stupid as hell... Thank you man!!! xD

Comment: Sure, no problem. Wood for the trees